# Azure Active Directory ServicePrincipal SecurityGroup AppRoleAssignment fails to resolve appRole

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Within Azure AD B2B I have created an application registration (the resource) with an appRole for "User" and "Application".

---

If I assign the servicePrincipal (the client) to this appRole -> the accessToken contains the appRole.

`servicePrincipal(client) <-> appRoleAssignment <-> servicePrincipal(resource)`

this works as expected

---

If I assign the serviceprincipal (the client) to a top level security group and assign the security group to the appRole -> the accessToken does NOT contain the appRole.

`servicePrincipal(client) <-> security group <-> appRoleAssignment <-> servicePrincipal(resource)`

this indirection works for users, am I missing something why this would not work for servicePrincipals?

Comment: you mean, there is an app "app1" with API permissions "Application.Read.All" and "User.Read.All" and a separate Service Principal(client) with a different Role assignment  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your steps are right.If you want to assign an app role to an service principle , you should assign one by one, it not works if you add a service principle into a group that assigned with an app role. As @juunas said , maybe this is something like a bug .

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have missed anything. It does indeed work for users.

It's either a bug or a feature :) Could be that application permissions are not wanted to be assigned via groups.
(which is what appRoles of type Application are)

Comment: In a scenario where Azure Managed identities are heavily used, the administrative overhead would be reduced if the servicePrincipal-securityGroup-appRoleAssignment-appRole-appRegistration would work...

Managed identity/user/servicePrincipal... entities... principals... ;)